# How to check if a gem support ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I should upgrade a Rails App 2.3 running with ruby 1.8 to ruby 1.9.1.

Rails 2.3 support ruby 1.9.1 without problem, but I am using many Gems (spec, capybara, authlogic, ...), and I am losing a lot of time checking the gems's documentation, but not always it's clear if they support ruby 1.9.1
The question is:
**what do you do to check if a gem supports ruby 1.9.1 ?**

thank you

Comment: Also, don't upgrade to 1.9.1, upgrade to 1.9.2 (or 1.9.3 which was recently released).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two good resources that I know of for this.

One is http://test.rubygems.org/ where you can see the results of test runs for gems on different architectures and versions of ruby as submitted by the community.

The other is http://isitruby19.com/. Another community powered site where you can see what gems are reported to run (or not) on Ruby 1.9.